# rviz drawing with the mouse: 3D shapes

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a package for letting the USER draw 3D shapes in rviz?  For instance, I would like the user to draw a sphere in rviz to select a subset of point cloud data.  Or maybe have the user draw a 3D vector on 3D sensor data.

Thanks so much.

Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10577/rviz-drawing-with-the-mouse:-3d-shapes/) by [mfleder](https://answers.ros.org/users/828/mfleder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only interactive interface we have in RViz is interactive markers:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/interactive_markers

It is available in ROS Electric.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2